# Iframe modal dynamic resize

Tags: iframe, joomla, modal-dialog

I'm trying to dynamically adjust the iframe window using the following code

```
<p><a class="modal" href="http://mysite.com" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 975, y:           650}}">Click here</a></p>
```

I've searched a few forums to no avail. I have a link in Joomla that opens this window and upon entering a username and password it routes you to another window. The problem is that the first window is smaller and a bunch of "whitespace" is shown. Doesn't look nice.

Thoughts?

Comment: Hi did you find out how to do that?